# Jquery effect does not work after few times

Tags: jquery, hover, mousehover

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script>    
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(this).find(".itemname").hide();
      $(".productborder").mouseover(function(){
    $(this).find(".itemname").animate({right:'160px'},"fast");
    $(this).find(".itemname").show();

 $(".productborder").mouseleave(function(){
 $(this).find(".itemname").animate({right:'0px'},"fast");
 $(".itemname").fadeOut(300);
    });

  });

});
</script> 
<html> 
 <div class="productborder">
  <p class="itemname"> Hello World </p>
  <img src="images/1.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" alt="wallet" />
 </div> <!-- end of productborder -->
</html>
```

This is my Jquery and HTML, The Jquery hover effect is working perfectly for the first few times, like say 4/5 times. Then the Itemname stuck in the right side and just appear and disappear. I am newbie in Jquery, any solution to solve this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your second event attachment is inside the first one, your brackets are closed on the wrong line. Reorganize them, make it so each event attachment is independent:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(this).find(".itemname").hide();
     $(".productborder").mouseover(function(){
      $(this).find(".itemname").animate({right:'160px'},"fast");
      $(this).find(".itemname").show();
     });
     $(".productborder").mouseleave(function(){
       $(this).find(".itemname").animate({right:'0px'},"fast");
       $(".itemname").fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `mouseover` event handler handler in `mouseleave`

Use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // You need to use .productborder selector instead of this
    $(".productborder").find(".itemname").hide();
    $(".productborder").mouseover(function() {
    });
    $(".productborder").mouseleave(function() {

    });
});
```